# Check the code. Don't understand why logic not work totally

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.google.common.collect.*;
public class start {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        start ex = new start();
        ex.doWork();

    }
    public void doWork(){
        List<String> asu2 = new ArrayList<String>();             // Create and initialization Lists
        List<String> rzs = new ArrayList<String>();                //        Order collection in descending order
        List<String> same = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int j=0;j<10;j++) {
            for (int i=0;i<2;i++){ asu2.add("M1");}
            asu2.add("M2");
            asu2.add("M3");
            asu2.add("M4");
            asu2.add("M5"); }
        System.out.println("Asu size :"+asu2.size());
        List<String> asu = Ordering.natural().sortedCopy(asu2);      //        Order collection in direct order
        Collections.reverse(asu);
        for (int j=0;j<5;j++) {
            for (int i=0;i<2;i++){ rzs.add("M1");}
            rzs.add("M2");
            rzs.add("M3");
            rzs.add("M4");
            rzs.add("M5"); }
        for (int j=0;j<3;j++) {
            for (int i=0;i<2;i++){ rzs.add("M1M2");}
            rzs.add("M2M3");
            rzs.add("M3M4");
            rzs.add("M4M5");
        }
        for (int j=0;j<2;j++) {
            for (int i=0;i<2;i++){ rzs.add("M1M2M3");}
            rzs.add("M2M3M4");
            rzs.add("M3M4M5");
            rzs.add("M1M4M5");
            rzs.add("M1M2M5");
        }
        System.out.println("Rzs size: "+rzs.size());


        for (int i=0;i<asu.size();i++){                                       // Поиск элементов типа M1<-->M1
            for (int j=0;j<rzs.size();j++)    {
                if (asu.get(i).equals(rzs.get(j)))
                {  System.out.println("("+asu.get(i)+") ASU <--> ("+rzs.get(j)+") RZS ");
                    System.out.println("i+ "+i+" j: "+j);
                    same.add(asu.get(i));
                    asu.remove(i); rzs.remove(j);
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i=0;i<asu.size();i++){                                        // Поиск элементов M1<-->M1M2
            for (int j=0;j<rzs.size();j++)    {
                if ((asu.get(i).equals(rzs.get(j))) | rzs.get(j).contains(asu.get(i)))
                {  System.out.println("("+asu.get(i)+") ASU <--> ("+rzs.get(j)+") RZS ");
                    same.add(asu.get(i));
                    asu.remove(i); rzs.remove(j);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Same size: " + same.size());
        System.out.println("Rzs size: "+rzs.size());
        for (int i=0;i<rzs.size();i++)
            System.out.println(rzs.get(i));
        System.out.println("Asu size: "+asu.size());
        for (int i=0;i<asu.size();i++)
            System.out.println(asu.get(i));




    }
}
```

Result:

```
Same size: 55
Rzs size: 2
M2M3
M3M4
Asu size: 5
M4
M2
M1
M1
M1
```

The logic is this. If `((asu.get(i).equals(rzs.get(j))) | rzs.get(j).contains(asu.get(i)))`, it is removed from the list.
Why were the elements still in the ASU (eg M4) and they have a couple (M3M4)?
Sorry for the structure of the code.

Comment: What logic are you talking about? What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: What do you see when you step through your code in a debugger?  This is what it is for.

Comment: The logic is easy. If exists an element in the ASU (eg M1), for him to find in the list RZS the same to him or made ​​up from it (such as M1, M1M2). That is, took element from ASU and if it corresponds to the M1 M1M2 in RZS, remove them from the list, write down to the list of M1 SAME

Comment: i know that debugger for this, but i can't find out error , while i'm debugging,therefore i'm asking here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite clear on your code, but when you remove an element from an ArrayList that you are iterating through, you do not want to increment the index, otherwise you will skip elements, e.g.:

```
ArrayList<...> list = ...;

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ) {
   if (shouldBeRemoved)
       list.remove(i);
   else
       ++ i;
}
```

In other words, if you remove the element at index i, the next element is now at i, not at i + 1.

Since you are skipping elements, then you may find that some that should have been checked are not, and thus are remaining in the list.

Comment: thanks to your reply, I changed the code to account for the reminder of how elements moves in the list and now everything is working as it should. thanks a lot!